# How to save and restore socket connection in socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I'm using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for creating android chat application. I store sockets to the array after users connection. My problem is when I restart server all stored sockets will be gone (as I expected). How to store client sockets info to retrieve them even after server restart. (Is it possible to save sockets in a file on database or better way )?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the sockets. Besides it's not even possible.
I don't know for android, but with Socket.io for browser, if the server goes down, clients will automatically try to reconnect with an interval.

So as soon as your server is listening again, clients will reconnect with no effort.
Try it yourself, launch server and client, kill the server, and relaunch it after some seconds.

If the android client doesn't have this feature, you just need to listen to the `disconnect` event client side, and when that happen, try to reconnect every second or so.